# ios - when presentViewController is closed not working

Tags: ios, qlpreviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I'm using a presentViewController which is working fine, see below:

I need to run a code(lets say an alert "I'm closed") when the when the presentViewController is completely closed or when the done/back button is pressed.

I don't wan to use completion block as this fires straight after the presentViewController is opened. I basically need to be able run some code after the presentViewController is closed or dismissed.

code:

```
QLPreviewController* myPopup = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
    myPopup.delegate = weakSelf;
    myPopup.dataSource = weakSelf;

    UIViewController* root = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];

    [root myPopup animated:YES  completion:nil ];
    //here put alert when it's closed or dismissed
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completion block doesn't work, because delay is to short? Try to put dispatch_after into completion block and set delay you need.

You can check for code sample here http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/tutorial-how-to-use-qlpreviewcontroller.html

Shortly:

```
QLPreviewController *previewController=[[QLPreviewController alloc]init];
previewController.delegate=self;
previewController.dataSource=self;
[self presentModalViewController:previewController animated:YES];
```

and delegate:

```
- (void)previewControllerDidDismiss:(QLPreviewController *)controller {
// display alert
}
```

Comment: I did that too, but whatever is inside the completion block it will fire whilst the QLPreviewController is opened. I need to display an alert once the done button is clicked and QLPreviewController is closed

Comment: what if QLPreviewController will delegate to presenting view controller as soon as done button pressed / view is going to disappear / dismiss completion block called?

Comment: Could be a solution, but I'm not sure I know how to do/implement it

Comment: QLPreviewController already has delegates previewControllerWillDismiss: and previewControllerDidDismiss: . You just need to handle them

Comment: I'm really sorry for my ignorance, but I'm very new in iOS development. Where can I find an example of your proposal?

Comment: you might me interested in [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28941178/ios-get-documents-url-when-qlpreviewcontroller-is-closed) post please :)