# iOS - get document's URL when QLPreviewController is closed

Tags: ios, presentmodalviewcontroller, qlpreviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have this code which previews the PDF file:

```
QLPreviewController *previewController=[[QLPreviewController alloc]init];
previewController.delegate=self;
previewController.dataSource=self;
[self presentModalViewController:previewController animated:YES];
```

Now, when I close `QLPreviewController` or `previewController` this method is called:

```
- (void)previewControllerDidDismiss:(QLPreviewController *)controller {
    NSLog(@"You closed the document");
}
```

Now, how I can return the document's or Pdf's URL when I call this method:

```
- (void)previewControllerDidDismiss:(QLPreviewController *)controller {
        //here I need to be able to get the PDF's URL or Data when is closed
    }
```

Can anyone please help?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/QLPreviewControllerDelegate/previewController:shouldOpenURL:forPreviewItem:). There is another method, that responds to user actions and returns needed URL:

```c
- (BOOL)previewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller
            shouldOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
           forPreviewItem:(id<QLPreviewItem>)item
```